# Umlaute (äöü) in image names served over php server

Tags: php, server, non-ascii-characters

I encountered a behaviour I can't get a grip on and am stuck googling it.

A picture named `ö.png` doesn't get found if I'm trying to serve it with `php -S localhost:4545`.

I attached a picture with - hopefully - all the necessary informations. It's a basic example to reproduce the behaviour.

I now that this works on a linux server but how could I get it to work no a PC serving via PHP?

[image]

Comment: So in short: you might get it to work somehow but nobody want's to do that and you shouldn't too.
I'm still interested in how this could be accomplished though.

Comment: Iterate through the files in the directory (e.g. `scandir`) and find the one you need, and `rawurlencode` it. That should give you the file name as the OS sees it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The `ö.png` whichs showed as `%C3%B6.png` really is `%25C3%25B6.png`. Might be obvious for others but I'm satisfied and feel a heavy stone lifted from my head. Thanks @deceze